# android service to listen to a specific port

Tags: android, service, port, listen

I want to know how to set an android service that listen to a specific port e.g. http://127.0.0.1:12345

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement your service and use the [`ServerSocket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html) class to listen for incoming connections and to act on them. Don't call `ServerSocket.accept()` on your UI thread, though. That'll cause your application to not respond. Instead, create a new thread or depending on your actual scenario, an `AsyncTask` might be sufficient.

Comment: @Steven Prentice Hello. your answer really helped me. I tried it in `AsyncTask` and it failed miserably.  Then I tried it in a separate Threads and it worked like magic. I was wondering why `ServerSocket` does this. Of course  tired it in the UI thread and it failed there too. Why is that ? What if I don't mind my Activity to hang since its sole purpose is to launch the server on click of a button for instance ?

Comment: @JasonKrs: It should work with AsyncTask, provided you conduct the ServerSocket business in doInBackground(). If you could share the code here then we could help more. As far as UI thread goes, that's the restriction (could wait for a task to finish in ~ 5secs) that Android provides because UI thread is responsible for a lot of things. From the docs: The system does not create a separate thread for each instance of a component. All components that run in the same process are instantiated in the UI thread, and system calls to each component are dispatched from that thread.

Comment: @UncaughtException Ahhh in `doInBackground()`... I think I may have not work like that... Maybe that's why it failed... Anyway lots of things have been done on ht e project so I won't reprogram that feature... I'll keed working with the old fashion Threads. ;-)